# Can I use the same React Native code for interacting with WebViews in iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am working on an application that is built in native Android and iOS. It's designed to be a moderately thin native wrapper around WebViews that encapsulate most of the main features of the application.

In the application we are using `Javascript injection` for the native device to communicate to the web. And for the web to communicate to the native app we use `WebView` delegates to intercept certain url requests.

We are now trying to solve the problem of maintaining two(iOS/Android) different implementations for this handling, because it would be more cost effective to move these frameworks to something that can be shared, like React Native.

Is anyone aware of examples repos or libraries in React Native that can match our needs? I found this [repository](https://github.com/jondot/awesome-react-native#web), and can see examples for Javascript handling, but not for `WebView` request interception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is yes, React Native can be a solution for you. I'm not sure if there area any packages out there that match your exact requirements. There are many, as you pointed out, so you'll just have to go through them and create a proof of concept. However, a smarter approach might be to simply expose the functionality you already developed to the RNBridge, then you can create a common API between the two platforms that does exactly what you need.

- [Native Modules (iOS)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html)
- [Native Modules (Android)](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)